# Java - Настройка VK SDK

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, vk-sdk

Я только что начал изучать язык Java, и хочу попробывать написать какого нибудь бота для VK. Но так как я Java изучать начал недавно, толком тут ничего не знаю. Прочитал оф. документацию о работе с API в Java. Там говорится про Maven/Gradle, а я с этим вообще никак не знаком, насколько я понял они добавляют зависимости в проект. В интернете решил поискать как их добавлять и что писать, не нашел толком ничего, можете пожалуйста помочь, как их добавить и как сделать что бы все это работало? Буду признателен.
Кстати, если это имеет какое то значение, я использую среду разработки Eclipse

Comment: Как это в интернете не нашли мануалов по Maven/Gradle?

Comment: я нашел один, на хабре, но там немного не понял. там написано как расписать мавен, а как подключить нету

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Вы уже вписали саму зависимость? Если да, то это, собственно, всё. Далее нужно только синхронизировать проект и пользоваться библиотекой.

Comment: histrionis, я если честно ничего еще не сделал, я в интернете искал что то по этому поводу, нашел только пост на хабре, но там не описывается как подключить его, только как вписать зависимости, да и с этим проблемы, там не указано конкретно куда вписывать, а я вообще не шарю

Comment: Не знаю, как сейчас в Eclipse, с Intellij IDEA идут встроенные maven и gradle. При создании проекта выбираете любой из них и в нём добавляете зависимость, дальше среда подскажет и сама скачает.

Answer (score 1):

В проекте должен быть файл `build.gradle` в нем будет конструкция следующего вида:

```
dependencies {
  ...
}
```

Внутрь этой конструкции нужно будет вписать зависимость `compile 'com.vk.api:sdk:0.5.12'`

Вот [гайдлайн](https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK) от самого VK